# iOS push notification alert message based on data in alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, alert, apple-push-notifications

All,

I am sending push notifications with data in a string.
Example:

```
{
    "aps": {
         "alert": "1,FriendsName,3,4,pink, green",
         "sound": "default"
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "aps": {
         "alert": "2,drinks, adress",
         "sound": "default"
    }
}
```

Now, I want the message in the alert to show a text, based on the values in the string.
So (pseudo-code): 
if the first character in "alert" = 1 => "alert = @"Color from %@ is %@", friendsName, pink
if the first character in "alert" = 2 => `"alert = @"Invite for %@ at %@", drinks, adress

Is this possible at all? And if so: how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible in the way you want. iOS handles the push notification and your app has no influence on the way the notification is presented. iOS will just present what you send in the notification.

However you can use [localization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW21) to achieve what you want:

```
"alert" : { "loc-key" : "ALERT_FORMAT", "loc-args" : [ "FriendsName", "pink"] },
```

Where the `ALERT_FORMAT` is a localization in you `Localizable.strings` file:

```
"ALERT_FORMAT" = "Color from %@ is %@"
```

But you will have to change the type of notification on the server, so the notification you send it an invite you will need to change the notification on the server.

So you will send something like this for the invite:

```
"alert" : { "loc-key" : "ALERT_INVITE", "loc-args" : [ "drinks", "adress"] },
```

Where the `ALERT_INVITE` is a localization in you `Localizable.strings` file:

```
"ALERT_INVITE" = "Invite for %@ at %@"
```

So you JSON for the push notification should look like:

```
{
    alert" : {
            "loc-key" : "ALERT_FORMAT",
            "loc-args" : [ "FriendsName", "pink"]
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Remmelt, Thanx for your reply. I will try this. Should I code this in handleBackgroundNotification? And if I want the 2 alerts, I should create ALERT_INVITE1 and ALERT_INVITE2 I presume?

Comment: ? `handleBackgroundNotification` ? Never heard of this message. But you should do it server side and just supply the used `loc-key` in you apps `Localizable.strings`

Comment: Hmm.. I can't find the Localizable.strings file... so I added it and also added localization in the project, but now the alert says "loc-key" : "ALERT_FORMAT", "loc-args" : [ "FriendsName", "pink"]. Shouldn't I have added the file by hand but via another method?

Comment: No just `Localizable.strings` should do the trick, but make sure it is set localization that is default for your app. And you should add a localization for each language that you app supports. I've also added an example of how the JSON should look like for the localized notification to work.

Comment: hmm.. maybe I am not creating the json correct in PHP... Maybe it sees the "loc-key"and "loc-args" as 1 string and therefore it is shown as the message... I will look into that

Comment: PHP is correct, now I get only ALERT_INVITE als alertstring on my screen.. no replacement with the other string or filling of the argument. Also created the Localizable.strings again and localized it for English and Dutch (language my device is on).

Comment: Weird, it's all from the Apple documentation. It should just work. make sure that the `Localizable.strings` is in your target. It that still doesn't work then I have bot idea what can be causing it.

Comment: Well, as always... After I, again, deleted all localization's and added them, it finaly worked! Strange...... but many thanx!